# Any way to "cast" units in CSS?

Tags: css, units-of-measurement, css-calc

I'm trying to change element rotation in CSS with the respect to screen width. Something like:

`transform: rotate(calc(30deg / 100vw / 1000px));`

Apparently, length arithmetic returns `<length>`, and dividing degrees on length is illegal. On the other hand `calc(30deg / 2)` works fine. Is there any CSS trick to "cast" length to `<number>`? I'd rather avoid JavaScript at the moment.

Comment: no there is no way simply because there is no logical result of dividing `deg` with `px` or with `vw` .. what should be the result of for example `10deg/10px`?

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's exactly my question: is there any way to convert `100vw / 1000px` result - which apparently is `<length>` - to a `<number>`. In that case calculation simplifies to a legal `10deg / 2` which solves my problem.

Comment: @AnnaAvina give this a read https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html it wont answer you question but maybe shed some light on why you cannot devide by a pixel

Comment: you need to define such conversion and the mathematical/logical relation of this. Suppose I ask you to convert *seconds* to *metre*, how you will do it? what does `vw/px` mean? it's not a length, it's undefined you cannot divide vw with px

Comment: @TemaniAfif To be fair, `vw` must be converted to pixels at some point, in order to render the page. It is not inconceivable that the browser could make the calculation at some point in the render process. That said, it's not always a good idea in terms of the performance of that rendering process to allow people to make those calculations. E.g., if it was `(100vw + 1000px)`; every time you calculate the width of the screen, something gets set to 1000px wider and you have to recalculate 100vw again...

Comment: The question is not "why can't I divide degrees and pixels." The question is "is it possible to convert `<length>` to `<number>` (or fwiw any other unit) in pure CSS the same way conversion between number and string is possible in JavaScript. If the answer is no - fine, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's why we need to define the relation. Actually you are converting `vw` to a pixel and you are probably thinking that dividing a pixel value by another will result on a number then we can use this number to divide the degree. I can do the same thinking by converting px to vw instead and then do the division to obtain another number. Unfortunately CSS cannot do this .. @anna I am pretty sure that what you are trying to achieve at the end can be done with this complex calcuation, can you share what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think the answer is no, irrespective of the technical (or logical) reasoning for that answer :).

Answer (score 2):

It seems, no.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation

> If compatible, the type resolves as described below (the following ignores precedence rules on the operators for simplicity):
>
> At `+` or `-`, check that both sides have the same type, or that one side is a  and the other is an `<integer>`. If both sides are the same type, resolve to that type. If one side is a `<number>` and the other is an `<integer>`, resolve to `<number>`.
>
> At `*`, check that at least one side is `<number>`. If both sides are `<integer>`, resolve to `<integer>`. Otherwise, resolve to the type of the other side.
>
> At `/`, check that the right side is `<number>`. If the left side is `<integer>`, resolve to `<number>`. Otherwise, resolve to the type of the left side.
>
> Note: Algebraic simplifications do not affect the validity of the `calc()` expression or its resolved type. For example, `calc(5px - 5px + 10s)` and `calc(0 * 5px + 10s)` are both invalid due to the attempt to add a length and a time.

Also, https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#calc-type-checking

Comment: can you share your use case where you need this? I saw a lot of cases where people were trying to consider the width of browser to adjust angle or other values and at the end we found a different way to tackle the problem without any calculation